# Is it possible to install EMET on Windows phone?

Tags: security

Is it possible to install EMET on Windows Phones, or is there any similar solutions?

By Windows Phone I meant Lumia series. (If hardware matters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. EMET is only compatible with the following OSs:

"Windows 7 Service Pack 1, Windows 8, Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2, Windows Server 2012, Windows Vista Service Pack 2, Windows XP Service Pack 3"

Windows phone (any version) is not mentionned and since it relies on a different kernel, there is no chance it'll work (You'll notice Windows 8 RT isn't mentioned either).

You can always check the [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39273) for exact requirements.

Comment: Not wanting to be too pedantic, but Windows Phone 8 shares its kernel with Windows 8; it does not share processor architecture though, which is more important here.